# Node.js stops listening (gets stuck) after executing query more than 6 times

Tags: node.js, express, reload, nodemon

I am using expressJs, This is the query which I am executing it multiple time

```
router.post('/Index_api/Reminder/Delete',function(req, res)
 {
      Reminder_Id = req.body; 
      DeleteRow('Reminders','Reminder_Id',Reminder_Id.Reminder_Id);

 });
```

int this is the DeleteRow Function

```
function DeleteRow(TableName,WCC, id)
 {

      var query ="Delete FROM `"+TableName + "` WHERE `"+ WCC +"` =" + id;

      conn.query(query,function(err,result)
       {
          if(err)
           {
               console.error(err);
               return;
           }else{
               console.log(result);
           }
      });
 }
```

I am posting data to this route like this:

```
function DeleteRow(id)
 {    
     $.post('/Index_api/Reminder/Delete',{
           Reminder_Id:id
     });
     $("#row"+id).remove();
 }
```

if I want to delete 6 records together there is no problem but by the 7th one is not executed and gets stuck.
I am also using nodemon and reload package.

Comment: what does the $ refer to?

Comment: That is jquery bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `router.post()` route handler is not returning any response.  Thus, the browser is still waiting for some sort of response.  The browser has a maximum number of connections it will make to any given host so once you have too many connections all sitting there waiting for a response, then the browser queues the next requests until one of the prior ones finishes.

Eventually those requests will time out, but that can take a long time.

To fix, just send a response from your route handler:

```
router.post('/Index_api/Reminder/Delete',function(req, res) {
      Reminder_Id = req.body; 
      DeleteRow('Reminders','Reminder_Id',Reminder_Id.Reminder_Id);
      res.send("ok");
});
```

---

Or, if you want the post to actually respond after `DeleteRow()` is done, you can let `DeleteRow()` send the right response by passing `res` to it and letting it send the response.

```
router.post('/Index_api/Reminder/Delete',function(req, res) {
      Reminder_Id = req.body; 
      DeleteRow('Reminders','Reminder_Id',Reminder_Id.Reminder_Id, res);
});

function DeleteRow(TableName, WCC, id, res) {
    var query = "Delete FROM `" + TableName + "` WHERE `" + WCC + "` =" + id;

    conn.query(query, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).send("delete failed");
        } else {
            res.send("delete OK");
        }
    });
}
```

Then, you should probably also change your client code to actually look at the returned status and act accordingly.

```
function DeleteRow(id) {    
     $.post('/Index_api/Reminder/Delete',{
           Reminder_Id:id
     }).then(function(result) {
         if (result.status == 200) {
             // successful
             $("#row"+id).remove();
         } else {
             // handle server error here
         }
     }, function(err) {
           // network error here
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude it really worked, just could please tell how I can check the status on the client side because I don't know where to get the response

Comment: @a.Sahel - I added more to the end of my answer about how to check the status in the client.