# Node express server get stucks

Tags: express

After running server for some time or sending requests. The node server just get stuck, no response at all.
There are no console.log messages either but when I click on server terminal and press Ctrl+C to stop it, all pending responses start being send, even I see the console.log.

Why it's happen and how do I fix it.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198932/node-js-stops-listening-gets-stuck-after-executing-query-more-than-6-times). Could be useful

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without more to go on, but remember that node (and therefore `express`) is single threaded, so I would check to make sure that you don't have any synchronous or blocking calls out to upstream services or the local filesystem/ database /etc.

Comment: Can't really help much without seeing your code, your current logging and what request it gets stuck on.  If you log all incoming requests, you should be able to isolate which request it gets stuck on and then perhaps have a smaller amount of code to then instrument and study for possible problems.

Comment: Does using console.log() cause this issue? I mean to get server stucked?

Comment: It's problem with my almost all node application. What I see in my experience, using console.log gets the server stuck. Is there any other way to log the data?

Comment: Does using console.log() cause this issue? I mean to get server stucked? – 
Kaneki Ghoul
 2 mins ago   Edit   Delete
It's problem with my almost all node application. What I see in my experience, using console.log gets the server stuck. Is there any other way to log the data?

Comment: No, there's nothing generically wrong with `console.log()`.  Using `console.log()` does not cause a problem unless there's something wrong with your stdout.  If you have `console.log()` reliably going to a terminal or to a file, you can run for years that way.  Now, if you have something funky going on with stdout or stderr and those get stuck, then maybe that could affect your app.

Comment: There are several other libraries that support logging.  You could use one of those, but if `console.log()` is causing you a problem, that's not the fault of `console.log()` - it's the fault of your environment and you could fix that problem and not have to replace your logging.